# How to pass multi-dimensional array to function?

Tags: c, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I am trying to pass a 2D array of variable size to a function to print it.but the code doesn't show the exact result of sum.

this is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROW 5
#define COLL 5

void print_arr(int a[][COLL],int m,int n){
int i,j,sum;
for(i=0;i<m;i++){
  for(j=0;j<n;j++){
         printf("a[%d][%d]=%d\n",i,j,a[i][j]);
     }
   }
}

int sum_arr(int a[][COLL],int m,int n){
int i,j,sum;

for(i=0;i<m;i++){
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        sum+=a[i][j];
    }
  }
  return sum;
}

int main (void){
int a[ROW][COLL];
int i,j,m,n;
int sum;

printf("enter rows:");scanf("%d",&m);
printf("enter coll:");scanf("%d",&n);

for(i=0;i<m;i++){
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        printf("a[%d][%d]=",i,j);scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
    }
}
print_arr(a,m,n);
printf("\n");

   sum=sum_arr(a,m,n);
   printf("sum=%d\n",sum);
   return 0;
}
```

this is the result of the code

```
enter rows:2
enter coll:3
a[0][0]=5
a[0][1]=8
a[0][2]=4
a[1][0]=7
a[1][1]=9
a[1][2]=6
a[0][0]=5
a[0][1]=8
a[0][2]=4
a[1][0]=7
a[1][1]=9
a[1][2]=6

sum=-1217388517
```

please tell me what's wrong with the code....

Comment: Try initializing `sum=0`

Comment: pointer_multi_array.c:15:21: error: ‘n’ undeclared here (not in a function)
pointer_multi_array.c: In function ‘main’:
pointer_multi_array.c:42:2: error: type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete

i got the above error when i change yhe size of array to n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the exact size of the second dimension of the array to the function, not `COLL`. change it to `m` (or `n`, whatever)
It passes the number `5` to the function while the number should be `3` :) How ever, this is not the main reason that you're code is not working, just a suggestion.
Initialize the variable `sum`. It will make your code work. e.g. `sum = 0;`
If you don't initialize it, you won't get any compile errors, but it points to a location of memory and reads thing been there before (not a valid amount) and uses it as the initial amount of that for sum.
So your array is being added to a non-valid amount, that's why your code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no technical problem with passing, but in sum_arr,
your variable sum does not start at 0 (but some strange value).

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize `sum` to `zero` in `sum_arr` function.